# How can I cast a class object to a list?

Tags: c#, generics

I'm fairly new to C# and I'm having trouble converting an object to a `List<T>`. I've been receiving the error "Cannot implicitly convert type `Attachment` to `System.Collections.Generic.List<Attachment>`. There are lots of posts about similar errors that I've looked over, but I can't seem to figure out what I'm missing.

My core object looks like:

```
public class Attachment 
{
    public Attachment() { }
    ...
}
```

It's being called in another class' constructor like so:

```
public class MyClass
{
    ...
    public List<Attachment> attachments { get; set; };
    ...
    public MyClass(JObject jobj)
    {
        ...
        //Attachments
        if (jobj["attachments"] != null)
        {
            attachments = (Attachment)jobj.Value<Attachment>("attachments");
        }
    }
}
```

The error is occurring in the last line of code where I'm trying to cast my Attachment object to the `List<attachments>`.  I understand what the message is saying, but everything I've tried doesn't work.

Comment: Since an `Attachment` isn't a `List`, why does this surprise you?  Or did you mean to add it to a `List` instead?

Comment: Would the two down voters care to explain why this is such a terrible question, aside from you thinking it's a simple mistake?

Comment: @Powerlord To be honest, I was about to be a downvoter because it did look somewhat trivial, but I reversed my vote pretty quickly when I actually thought about it, because I'd say there is nothing unclear about this question. It states the desired behavior and the attempt. So definitely +1 from me now. I think this is a great question, actually. To the point, yet complete.

Comment: Trebor, post your json.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are setting a `List<T>` to a `T`.

```
attachments = (Attachment)jobj.Value<Attachment>("attachments");
```

Instead, you probably want to *Add* it. But don't forget to instantiate the list first.

```
attachments = new List<Attachment>();
attachments.Add((Attachment)jobj.Value<Attachment>("attachments"));
```

---

Think about it in terms that don't involve generics. Say I have an `int x` and I set it to a `string` constant.

```
int x = "test";
```

What would that mean? Those are complete different types. That's kind of like the conversion you're asking the compiler to perform. The type on the left has to be (a polymorphic parent of or) the type on the right.

Comment: Matthew, since it's a field (public List<Attachment> attachments { get; set; };), does it need to be instantiated?

Comment: @Trebor First off, minor thing: just a term of the art--when you have a getter and setter, that's called a "property," not a "field." Not a big deal, just so you know in the future. And second, I'm not completely sure I know what you mean. I do instantiate it in the first line of my code. I did add that a few seconds after originally posting my answer since I forgot to include it, but does what I have there now not work?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on the term.  I'm still getting used to the verbage.  It was your addition of the instantiation that surprised me.  Intellisense (or the red error highlighting) indicates that it will work with or without the instantiation line so I was trying to understand it better.

Comment: @Trebor yep, I definitely know that feeling. And yeah, Intellisense catches compile-time errors. The compiler understands that you can't convert from one type to another (without a conversion existing, as your error says), but the fact that it wasn't instantiated is a *runtime* error. Properties take the default value of their type (for reference types, like `List<T>`, that's `null`). So without that line, it's a `NullReferenceException` waiting to happen. But the compiler isn't *quite* smart enough to pick up on that for a case like this.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use the `ToObject` method

```
List<Attachment> attachments = jobj["attachments"].ToObject<List<Attachment>>();
```

Comment: I think it depends on what the poster is really wanting.. if they're trying to assign a preexisting list to a list, then yes, this is what they want. If they're trying to add a single item to a list, then Matthew's answer is what they want

Comment: @cost If the property name is `attachments (jobj["attachments"])`, then I think we can assume it is a List/Array. But of course, can not be sure before seeing the json.

Comment: @EZI Thank you for your help.  I'm trying to actually modify someone else's code so I may still need your solution.